# How to access a server-client application on another system through a wireless network

Tags: networking, wampserver

I'm developing a kind of web-based intranet application that runs on wamp, other systems/hosts should be able to connect to the server and access data from the central database using their browser. I can get a host to connect to the server using WIFI but I can't figure out how to access the application as if it's online. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type the IP Address of the server in your browser.

Comment: Thanks I could imagine that, but how do I get the IP address? Just feeling lazy and probably hoping to learn something new.

Comment: The best way around this is to assign a static IP Address to server machine, and you can always access the server from same IP address.
I suppose you want to get the server IP address from your client system other wise getting the machine IP address is very straight forward (e.g ifconfig will give you system's IP address on Linux)

Comment: Thanks again. Let me browse around on how to assign static address.